# razor syntax within Javascript

Tags: javascript, razor

I am attempting to extract data from a Json object in .NET MVC 4.

Here is a code snippet of my razor view:

```
var data = (function($)
           {
            var dataModel = @(new HtmlString(new 
             System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
              .Serialize(Model)));
```

This won't run due the "@" sign within the javascript code.

How can I fix this so that razor switches back to .NET managed mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning that you could completely and safely ignore. Run the code and it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks Darin.. it does run fine, but when I try to publish, it fails due to the warning. Is there a way I can disable that?